# Is it true that whatever current enters a battery, also leaves the battery? Why?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, conservation-laws, electric-current, charge

How is it true that whatever current enters a battery also leaves the battery?

Is it due to one of the Kirchhoff's laws? Can anyone show how that is? How can I reach this conclusion logically/mathematically?

Comment: Imagine building up more and more charge in the battery until it can’t take anymore and explodes...

Comment: Conservation of matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Current is coulombs per second. If we have $I_i$ entering the battery and $I_o$ leaving the battery, the change in electric charge of the battery over time is $t(I_i-I_o)$. If $I_i\neq I_o$, the charge will change over time and most things don't prefer to be electrically charged.

Answer (score 2):

Yes at steady state, current entering has to be equal to the current leaving and this is true for any part of the circuit.

If that were not the case that would mean steady state hasn't been reached yet, the charges are building up somewhere and surface charge redistribution will occur (*those excess charges reside on the wire surface and create the necessary E-field*) which will eventually force the current to be steady throughout the circuit. This process happens **very** fast, somewhat near the *well known* speed of light.

Also in case of inductors, the current takes some time to reach steady state but before that we can say that the current through different elements (the circuit) is more or less the same at a particular instant.

Answer (score 2):

There is another issue here, besides the answers already given.  There is an oxidation/reduction reaction going on inside the battery, such that one ionic species gives up an electron at the negative terminal of the battery, and that electron travels to the positive terminal of the battery in order to combine with a positively charged ion.  Both ionic reactions must take place to generate current flow, which necessarily means that the amount of charge leaving the negative electrode must enter the positive electrode, or the chemical reaction that is generating those electrons will be shut down.  For more info, see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/electrochem.html